# Using Subquery with SUM in SELECT statement

Tags: ms-access-2010

Here is my scenario:

I have the following data stored in a table (CustomerSales):

```
CustomerCode   CustomerName   SalesAmt   Year
001            Customer 1     $10.00     2014
001            Customer 1     $15.00     2014
001            Customer 1     $5.00      2013
002            Customer 2     $5.00      2014
002            Customer 2     $5.00      2013
```

I would like a report to display customer sales by year. Example desired outcome:

```
Customer Code   Customer Name   2013 Sales   2014 Sales
001             Customer 1      $5.00        $25.00
002             Customer 2      $5.00        $5.00
```

My current query is returning the total year amount for ALL customers, not just that line. Example:

```
Customer Code   Customer Name   2013 Sales   2014 Sales
001             Customer 1      $10.00        $30.00
002             Customer 2      $10.00        $30.00
```

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT [CustomerSales].[CustomerCode], [CustomerSales].[CustomerName],
    (SELECT Sum([CustomerSales].[SalesAmt]) 
     FROM [CustomerSales] 
     WHERE [CustomerSales].[Year] = "2013") AS "2013 Sales",
    (SELECT Sum([CustomerSales].[SalesAmt]) 
     FROM [CustomerSales] 
     WHERE [CustomerSales].[Year] = "2014") AS "2014 Sales",
FROM [CustomerSales]
GROUP BY [CustomerSales].[CustomerCode], [CustomerSales].[CustomerName], [CustomerSales].[Year];
```

I am using Access 2010. Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

NOTE: I'm sure this is a simple mistake, but I've been out of the SQL game for a while now >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not have Access installed to test my query.   I have written the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT  CustomerSales.CustomerCode, 
        CustomerSales.CustomerName,
        SUM(IF(CustomerSales.Year='2013',CustomerSales.SalesAmt,0)) as "2013 Sales",
        SUM(IF(CustomerSales.Year='2014',CustomerSales.SalesAmt,0)) as "2014 Sales"
FROM CustomerSales
GROUP BY CustomerSales.CustomerCode, CustomerSales.CustomerName, CustomerSales.Year;
```

Apparently, Access has a similar IF construct IIF (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx)

So, you should hypothetically be able to reconstruct your query thus:

```
SELECT  [CustomerSales].[CustomerCode], 
        [CustomerSales].[CustomerName],
    SUM(IIF([CustomerSales].[Year]='2013',[CustomerSales].[SalesAmt],0)) as "2013 Sales",
    SUM(IIF([CustomerSales].[Year]='2014',[CustomerSales].[SalesAmt],0)) as "2014 Sales"        
FROM [CustomerSales]
GROUP BY [CustomerSales].[CustomerCode], [CustomerSales].[CustomerName], [CustomerSales].[Year];
```

Please let me know if this works for you :)